# Image View Tap Gesture

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift, so I make exercises through apple developer center, I coded with the project named Food Tracker. My codes is totally the same with the site samples, but when I click the image there is nothing to see. So it doesn't work.
and there is no error.

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    //This info dictionary contains multiple representations of the images, and this uses the original. 
    let selectedImage=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]as! UIImage

    //set photoImageView to display the selected image 
    photoImageView.image=selectedImage

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil )
    print("picker image")
}
```

When i click the image image picker doesn't work. And "picker image" is not showed.

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Could you check if the imageview has the `userInteractionEnabled` flag set to true?

Comment: did you enable user interaction on imageview ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is  because of the image view interaction=NO, so choose the image view and see the attributes inspector, then you will find "interaction" label, if checkbox "user interaction enabled" is not checked, you will get the error, so check the user interaction enabled, then you will get the right answer.
   The important thing is just the attribute called "user interaction enabled" of image view.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy5Vo.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `UIImageView`'s `userInteractionEnabled` is `NO` by default. It needs to set `YES` for receiving touch events.

Answer (score 0):

When I code like this , i also have another error which is something like the following."there is more than one view". So when i click the tap gesture, i find there is not only one "Photo Image View" below the "gestureRecognizers", so i delete the image view and make there only one image view below the gesture "gestureRecognizers", then i don't have the error..

So at last you should get this like the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJawl.png)